# Elegantly suppress Twill output in Python

Tags: python, twill

I've recently been playing around with Twill and BeautifulSoup to do some basic screenscraping. However, it appears that one of the commands I'm using is printing a bunch of undesired output to the screen. Here's a quick snippet of the code I use to login to the site in question:

```
from twill.commands import *
from twill import get_browser

mybrowser = get_browser()
mybrowser.go(url)
mybrowser.showforms()
formvalue('1', 'email', email)
formvalue('1', 'password', password)
mybrowser.submit()
result = show()
```

At the moment, I'm using the "redirect_output()" function to pipe the undesired output to a garbage-filled text file...but this seems like a very hackish solution. Is there a more elegant way to avoid excessive printing with the commands above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best idea is:

```
import os
f = open(os.devnull,"w")
twill.set_output(f)
```

Comment: Did not know about os.devnull until now...very cool. Thanks a lot!